# How to add href to popup (infoWindow) in ArcGIS API?

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm a newbie in programming. I'm trying to make a href link inside of arcGIS js infoWindow (popup). I don't know how to make this link work. The code that I'm trying is shown below.
Could you please suggest a solution?

```
    map.on("click", addPoint);
    function addPoint(evt) {
        var latitude = evt.mapPoint.getLatitude();
        var longitude = evt.mapPoint.getLongitude();
        var link = "<a href="www.google.com">Google Office</a>"
        map.infoWindow.setTitle("Coordinates");
        map.infoWindow.setContent(
          "lat: " + latitude.toFixed(7) + "<br> lon: " + longitude.toFixed(7) + "<br> Link: " + link
        );
        map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint, map.getInfoWindowAnchor(evt.screenPoint));
      };
```

Comment: Can you please help me out at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69630872/display-info-window-on-the-multiple-coordinates-on-the-arcgis-map-in-next-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you replace "www.google.com" with 'http://www.google.com' (note the single quotes).

```
var link = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google Office</a>"
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not open a link.

Comment: Does the popup open? Do you get a link to click on in the popup, but nothing happens when you click on it? Or do you not see anything in the popop?

Comment: Popup works but when I click on the link, nothing happens [image here](http://i59.tinypic.com/wlyb94.png)

Comment: Edited the answer, just to make sure we are on the same page.

Comment: @DanJurgella Can you please help me out at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69630872/display-info-window-on-the-multiple-coordinates-on-the-arcgis-map-in-next-js